# add two vertical lines in barchart

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to add a two vertical lines to a barchart I made, but am having trouble.

Examples data set

```
data<-data.frame(area=rep(c("ES","OC","VB"),each=2,times=2),num=c(0,10,23,40,25,60,80,45,10,25,10,0),
    bin=rep(c(85,90),times=3))
```

barchart code.  Most of the formatting code is for the actual data set.

```
require(lattice)         
barchart(num~as.factor(bin), data=data,col=c("black","lightslategray","light gray"),
    groups = area, stack = F, horizontal=F,xlab="Shell Length (mm)",ylab="Frequency (N)",
    scales=list(y=list(alternating=1,tck=-1,limits=c(0,400),
    at=c(0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400),
    labels=c("0","50","100","150","200","250","300","350","400"),relation="same")),
    par.settings = list( grid.pars = list(fontfamily = 'serif'),axis.line=list(col=0)),
    panel = function(...) {
           lims<-current.panel.limits()
             panel.barchart(...)
           panel.abline(v=as.factor(80),col="red",lty=2)
           panel.abline(v=as.factor(90),h=0,col="black")
           panel.abline(h=lims$ylim[1],v=lims$xlim[1])
           panel.text(25,200,"OC (N = 1,947)",col="black",cex=.8)
           panel.text(25,185,"ES (N = 2,623)",col="lightslategray",cex=.8)
           panel.text(25,170,"VB (N = 2,780)",col="light gray",cex=.8)
      })
```

When I run the code one vertical line in on the graph, but the second line does not show up.  Regardless of what value I put as v the one line does not change position.

R information

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[7] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] plyr_1.8.3          Hmisc_3.17-0        ggplot2_1.0.1      
 [4] Formula_1.2-1       survival_2.38-1     car_2.0-26         
 [7] MASS_7.3-40         xlsx_0.5.7          xlsxjars_0.6.1     
[10] rJava_0.9-7         latticeExtra_0.6-26 RColorBrewer_1.1-2 
[13] lattice_0.20-31
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You convert `bin` to a factor at the beginning of your code (although it would be coerced to a factor even if you didn't) creating a categorical axis with implicit primary tick coordinates of 1 and 2 as the center of each group of bars, rather than 85 and 90 as you were expecting. See for example what happens when you change your code as follows:

```
       panel.abline(v=1,col="red",lty=2)
       panel.abline(v=2,h=0,col="black")
       panel.abline(h=lims$ylim[1],v=lims$xlim[1])
       panel.text(1,200,"OC (N = 1,947)",col="black",cex=.8)
       panel.text(1.5,185,"ES (N = 2,623)",col="lightslategray",cex=.8)
       panel.text(2,170,"VB (N = 2,780)",col="light gray",cex=.8)
     })
```

Comment: Thank you.  Now I understand that the x axis variables are treated as the levels of the factor (i.e., 1 ,2, 3, etc.)  not the value that is shown on the graph.  So when I need to add a line to my actual data I use the number of the factor not the value on the axis.

Answer (score 1):

```
barchart(data$num~as.factor(data$bin), groups=data$area, 
panel=function(x,y,...){ 
       panel.barchart(x,y,...) 
       panel.abline(v=1,col.line="red",lty=3)
       panel.abline(v=2,col.line="blue",lty=2)})
```

The above should do it.

[image]

Comment: `barchart` can take `data` argument so variable names can be provided without pointing to enclosing `data$` object